# continueUserActivity not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I have an app that supports Universal Links. Everything looks properly set up. I have an `apple-app-site-association` file on the server, appropriate link added to Associated Domains and also I added `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` to the AppDelegate.
Finally, I added a link to my Notes app and when I click the link and hold it I'm able to see button Open in "MyApp". When I tap the button iOS opens the app but `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` is never called. What makes this even more mysterious is that `application:willContinueUserActivityWithType:` gets called (of course I return YES here)

UPDATE: If my app is not running in the background mode and I click the link I get my app opened and I get `NSUserActivity` object in `launchOptions` parameter of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. But still `application:willContinueUserActivityWithType:` isn't called.

Comment: **It's now done in the SceneDelegate and NO LONGER done in the app delegate. Really stupid**

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but I faced this issue myself. Did you migrate to a newer version of Swift? In my case, the function stopped working after the migration. The function was renamed from

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool`

to

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer! I used xCode's Swift conversion tool, but somehow it missed that function. Since Swift doesn't have an @Override annotation like Java/Android, I didn't get any errors from the compiler...didn't even think to manually check the method signatures.

Comment: great. Thanks @Franlon . Solved my problem too. I've copied the whole code from a project including the old function..but in one i was at version 4.1 and in the new one 4.2

Comment: 3 days I wasted trying to fix this. Ugh. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you! Lost around 8 hours on this. Fixed all warnings, and none said anything about the outdated method signature. At least I learned more about UIScenes's, but like Apple seriously... not the best Xcode you have ever made!